# How do I assign an IP to a web server running on an Android hotspot?

Tags: java, android, sockets, nanohttpd

I am running a NanoHTTPD web server on an Android host device which is broadcasting a Wifi hotspot with no internet connectivity.  My host application is advertising a TCP service through NsdManager that a client app connected to the Wifi hotspot will look for.

So far logging on the host device indicates that the server is starting and NSD service is registered properly.  However, my phone app is not sending any requests to my web server that handles the service (the app doesn't find an available service).  Logging shows that my host server's socket does not have an IP address.  However, when my phone connects to the Wifi hotspot it obtains an IP address.  Is there something special I am missing in order for the host itself to obtain an IP address on the hotspot network?

Here are my NanoHTTPD server startup functions:

```
@Override
public void start(final int timeout, boolean daemon) throws IOException {
    super.start(timeout, daemon);

    ServerSocket socket = getMyServerSocket();
    if (!socket.isBound()) {
        final InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        final int port = getListeningPort();
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket bound manually.");
        }
    }
    if (DEBUG) {
        final InetAddress ip = socket.getInetAddress();
        final int port = socket.getLocalPort();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Bound socket to %s:%d", ip.getHostAddress(), port));
    }

    initRegistrationListener();
    registerService();
}

private void initRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo aInfo) {
            mServiceName = aInfo.getServiceName();
            Log.d(TAG, "Nsd service registered: " + mServiceName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo aInfo, int aErrorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Nsd service registration failed.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo aInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Nsd service unregistered.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo aInfo, int aErrorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Nsd service unregister failed.");
        }
    };
}

private void registerService() {
    final int port = getMyServerSocket().getLocalPort();
    final InetAddress addr = getMyServerSocket().getInetAddress();

    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setServiceName("MyTcpService");
    serviceInfo.setServiceType("_my-service._tcp");
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    serviceInfo.setHost(addr);

    mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Registered service at %s:%d.", addr.getHostAddress(), port));
    }
}
```

Logcat output from running these functions:

```
11-06 10:56:31.814  2869  2869 D JsonServer: Socket is bound to :::48376
11-06 10:56:31.816  2869  2869 D JsonServer: Registered service at :::48376.
11-06 10:56:34.199  2869  3733 D JsonServer: Nsd service registered: MyTcpService
11-06 10:57:14.160  2869  3733 D JsonServer: Nsd service unregistered.
```

Any ideas why my bound ServerSocket has no IP address?

Comment: What are you messing around with ip addresses and binding!? You should only let the ServerSocket start listening on a port. Thats all.

Comment: My NanoHttpD shows as ip 192.168.43.1 which is the normal ip for an Android hotspot. You can use that in your clients.

Comment: Any messing around with binding ip addresses is the result of attempting to debug this code.  :)  I assumed Android/NanoHTTPD would handle this for me.

Is there an API to get the hotspot IP address or is hard coding required?

Comment: The serversocket will tell you the ip of the device where it is running on. Thats what i told you. A client connected to the hotspot can discover its own ip address. If it is 192.168.43.# then it knows the server is the 1.